# write file need to optimised for heavy traffic

Tags: c#, io

i am very new to C#, and this is my first question, please be gentle on me

I am trying to write a application to capture some tick data from the data provider, below is the main part of the program

```
void zf_TickEvent(object sender, ZenFire.TickEventArgs e)
{

    output myoutput = new output();

    myoutput.time = e.TimeStamp;
    myoutput.product = e.Product.ToString();
    myoutput.type = Enum.GetName(typeof(ZenFire.TickType), e.Type);
    myoutput.price = e.Price;
    myoutput.volume = e.Volume;

    using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("c:\\log222.txt"))
    {

        writer.Write(myoutput.time.ToString(timeFmt) + ",");
        writer.Write(myoutput.product + "," );
        writer.Write(myoutput.type + "," );
        writer.Write(myoutput.price + ",");
        writer.Write(myoutput.volume + ",");

    }
```

i have successfully write the data into the text file, however i know that this method will be call like 10000 times a second during peak time, and open a file and append it many times a second is very inefficient, i was pointed to use a buffer or some sort, but i have no idea how to do it, i try reading the document but i still dont understand, thats why i turn in here for help.

Please give me some (working) snippet code so i can pointed to the write direction. thanks

EDIT: i have simplified the code as much as possible

```
    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = File.AppendText("c:\\output.txt"))
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}",
                        e.TimeStamp.ToString(timeFmt),
                        e.Product.ToString(),
                        Enum.GetName(typeof(ZenFire.TickType), e.Type),
                        e.Price,
                        e.Volume));
    }
```

ED has told me to make my stream to a field, how is the syntax looks like? can anyone post some code to help me? thanks a lot

Comment: A possible alternative could be to push writes operations into a queue, and fire a background thread that writes the content of the queue eventually when possible

Comment: I've already shown how to make a field (`private StreamWriter _writer;`)

Comment: @ andrey, thanks, please read part 2 of my question in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884106/write-file-need-to-optimised-for-heavy-traffic-part2

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would use String.Format:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\log222.txt", true))
        {
            writer.AutoFlush = true;
            writer.Write(String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},", myoutput.time.ToString(timeFmt), 
                myoutput.product, myoutput.type, myoutput.price, myoutput.volume);
        }
```

If you use `@` before string you don't have to use double `\`.

This is much faster - you write only once to the file instead of 5 times. Additionally you don't use `+` operator with strings which is not the fastest operation ;)

Also - if this is multithreading application - you should consider using some lock. It would prevent application from trying to write to the file from eg. 2 threads at one time.

Comment: -1 AutoFlush on a `StreamWriter` is `false` by default, [so the writes are buffered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce2kyyb4.aspx).  This is why we don't make assumptions about performance.  Test or (at least) read the documentation.

Comment: @EdS. - true, forgot to write that line. Corrected - thx. BTW - don't make assumption about made tests - I use this way often to write down several millions of lines every time. It works pretty fast.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem.  The OP has already said that this function will run many times per second.  You propose that combining N calls to `Write()` into one will increase performance because it will reduce the number of times the buffer is flushed and the data is written to disk.  This is wrong for two reasons.  The first I already mentioned.  The *real* problem is that the file is opened, written to, flushed to disk, and closed for each call to the function.  *That* is the real problem, and your answer does not address it.  A good first attempt would be to stop creating a new stream

Comment: ...each time the function is called.

Comment: Ah yes, actually you're right. I focused mainly on the `Write()` method. My bad. I guess then, combining Andrey Atapin answer with using `String.Format()` would be the best solution.

Comment: After reading my first comment... It sounds a lot more preachy and arrogant than I intended. Sorry.

Comment: thanks ED. this is the main issue i have to address. HOW would i change my program so it does not call a new stream every time the function is called? can you point me to the right direction please? Maybe use an array to hold the data and write it when it is full? how would best to structure it?

Comment: @clayton Leung: andrey has the answer for you; make the stream a field and close it only when you are done with it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a field for the stream instead of a local variable. Initialize it in constructor once and don't forget to close it somewhere. It's better to implement `IDisposable` interface and close the stream in `Dispose()` method.

[IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx)

```
class MyClass : IDisposable {
    private StreamWriter _writer;

    MyClass() {
        _writer = File.App.....;
    }

    void zf_TickEvent(object sender, ZenFire.TickEventArgs e)
    {

        output myoutput = new output();

        myoutput.time = e.TimeStamp;
        myoutput.product = e.Product.ToString();
        myoutput.type = Enum.GetName(typeof(ZenFire.TickType), e.Type);
        myoutput.price = e.Price;
        myoutput.volume = e.Volume;


        _writer.Write(myoutput.time.ToString(timeFmt) + ",");
        _writer.Write(myoutput.product + "," );
        _writer.Write(myoutput.type + "," );
        _writer.Write(myoutput.price + ",");
        _writer.Write(myoutput.volume + ",");

    }

    public void Dispose() { /*see the documentation*/ }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input, however i want to stress that this method is going to be call about 10000 times a second during peak time. I know i need to implement a buffer of some sort but i have no idea how to implement it. can someone help me how to do it (with some simple code)?

Comment: Never tried, but you may use the [BufferedStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.aspx) over a filestream, and create the StreamWriter over this buffered stream.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things you can do

Step 1. Make sure you don't make many io calls and string concatenations.

```
Output myOutput = new Outoput(e); // Maybe consruct from event args?

// Single write call, single string.format
writer.Write(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}", 
  myOutput.Time.ToString(), 
  myOutput.Product, 
  ...);
```

This I recommend regardless of what your current performance is. I also made some cosmetic changes (variable/property/class name casing. You should look up the difference between variables and properties and their recommended case etc.)

Step 2. Analyse your performance to see if it does what you want. If it does, no need to do anything further. If performance is still too bad, you can

- Keep the file open and close it when your handler shuts down.
- Write to a buffer and flush it at regular intervals.
- Use a logger framework like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) that internally handles the above for you, and takes care of hairy issues like access to the log file from multiple threads.