# Write file need to optimised for heavy traffic part 3

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, io

this question is a continuation of the first 2 part, anyone who is interested to see where I come from you can refer to part 1 and part 2, but it is not necessary.

[write file need to optimised for heavy traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828372/write-file-need-to-optimised-for-heavy-traffic)

[Write file need to optimised for heavy traffic part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884106/write-file-need-to-optimised-for-heavy-traffic-part-2)

now i have a working snippet, the relevant part is below:

```
    public static class memoryStreamClass
    {
        static MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();

        public static void fillBuffer(string outputString)
        {
            byte[] outputByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(outputString);

            ms1.Write(outputByte, 0, outputByte.Length);

            if (ms1.Length > 8100)
            {
                emptyBuffer(ms1);
                ms1.SetLength(0);
                ms1.Position = 0;
            }
        }

        static void emptyBuffer(MemoryStream ms)
        {
            FileStream outStream = new FileStream("c:\\output.txt", FileMode.Append);

            ms.WriteTo(outStream);
            outStream.Flush();
            outStream.Close();
        }
```

the above snippet works fine, and bug free. it output around 8KB of data every write.

now i try to multithread the above code to enhance the performance of an IO write bottleneck and problems appeared. the below snippet is what i tried to attempted.

Basically i have 2 identical memoryStream, if say ms1 is full, it writes ms1 into file and switch to ms2 while ms1 is writing, and vice versa.

```
    public static class memoryStreamClass
    {
        static MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();
        static MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
        static int c = 1;

        public static void fillBuffer(string outputString)
        {
            byte[] outputByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(outputString);

            if (c == 1)
            {
                ms1.Write(outputByte, 0, outputByte.Length);

                if (ms1.Length > 8100)
                {
                    c = 2;

                    Thread thread1 = new Thread( () => emptyBuffer(ms1));
                    thread1.Start();

                    ms1.SetLength(0);
                    ms1.Position = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ms2.Write(outputByte, 0, outputByte.Length);

                if (ms2.Length > 8100)
                {
                    c = 1;

                    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => emptyBuffer(ms2));
                    thread2.Start();

                    ms2.SetLength(0);
                    ms2.Position = 0;

                }
            }
        }
```

the above code can compile and run, however, the output write is not always 8KB, and it writes way too frequently (than my single thread program). can someone enlighten my and points out what is wrong with my program? thank you very much

Comment: as @channs points out, if any of your previous questions were answered correctly you should mark those answers as accepted.

Comment: Why dont you get your code reviewed on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Combining `static` and Streams is rarely a good idea.  When you combine static state and multithreading, you're begging for bad things to happen.  What you have here is just wrong.  Scrap it and start over with multithreading considered.

Comment: @Austin Salonen i have try to change my coded to instance and my output is even worst, i have write to a file that is 0 KB, i just dont understand it. can anyone help me?

Comment: @Jodrell, sorry, i went back now, and mark all my previous questions, i am new to stackoverflow and dont know the right way of doing it

Comment: Yeah.. if you are going to use multiple buffers with threads, allocate a buffer object, fill it, queue it to other threads/threadpool and IMMEDIATELY create another one at the same *buffer so that there is no chance of two threads ever operating on the same buffer.  Don't continually create/terminate/delete/GC threads.  Don't try to communicate via MemoryStreams - it's going to be inefficient at best, even if you don't screw up which will be fairly easy to do.  Do communicate by queueing *buffer instances - largish ones, (the buffer not the pointer:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is horribly broken, and your idea of using two buffers to improve performance is almost certainly an over-optimisation.  However, there's one obvious problem in this block of code:

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread( () => emptyBuffer(ms1));
thread1.Start();

ms1.SetLength(0);
ms1.Position = 0;
```

What this code does is:

- start a thread to process a buffer
- immediately clear that buffer

The problem is that your "clear" code will *almost certainly* execute before your thread has a chance to start (because generally speaking, an executing method will complete before the thread context changes).  So, by the time you call `emptyBuffer`, your `MemoryStream` is already empty.

Your statics are a bad idea; if you were to pass a non-static instance to the `emptyBuffer` method, and then set `ms1 = new MemoryStream()`, you would probably have *better* functioning code.  But ultimately, this code is conceptually flawed and you should look at redesigning.

Comment: I was typing up pretty much the exact same thing.  +1