# Write file need to optimised for heavy traffic part 4

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, io

this is a continuation of part 3

[Write file need to optimised for heavy traffic part 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526856/write-file-need-to-optimised-for-heavy-traffic-part-3)

as my code changed somewhat i think it is better to open a new thread.

```
    public class memoryStreamClass
    {
        static MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();
        static MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
        static int c = 1;

        public void fillBuffer(string outputString)
        {
            byte[] outputByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(outputString);

            if (c == 1)
            {
                ms1.Write(outputByte, 0, outputByte.Length);

                if (ms1.Length > 8100)
                {
                    c = 2;

                    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => emptyBuffer(ref ms1));
                    thread1.Start();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ms2.Write(outputByte, 0, outputByte.Length);

                if (ms2.Length > 8100)
                {
                    c = 1;

                    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => emptyBuffer(ref ms2));
                    thread2.Start();
                }
            }
        }

        void emptyBuffer(ref MemoryStream ms)
        {
            FileStream outStream = new FileStream(string.Format("c:\\output.txt", FileMode.Append);

            ms.WriteTo(outStream);
            outStream.Flush();
            outStream.Close();

            ms.SetLength(0);
            ms.Position = 0;

            Console.WriteLine(ms.Position);
        }
```

there are 2 things i have changed changed from the code in part 3.

1. the class and method is changed to non-static, the variables are still static tho.
2. i have move the memorystream reset length into the emptyBuffer method, and i use a ref parameter to pass the reference instead of a copy to the method.

this code compiled fine and runs ok. However, i run it side by side with my single thread program, using 2 computers, one computer runs the single thread, and one computer runs the multithread version, on the same network. i run it for around 5 mins. and the single threaded version collects 8333KB of data while the multithread version collects only 8222KB of data. (98.6% of the single thread version)

its first time i have do any performance comparison between the 2 version. Maybe a should run more test to confirm it. but base on looking the code, any masters out there will point out any problem?

i haven't putting any code on lock or threadpooling at the moment, maybe i should, but if the code runs fine, i dont want to change it and break it. the only thing i will change is the buffer size, so i will eliminate any chance of the buffer fill up before the other is emptied.

any comments on my code?

Comment: I looked at all the previous installments of this question and it looks like **you don't have an actual problem**. You just anticipate a problem and try to fix it preemptively. First, implement it in it's simplest form, pinpoint the "actual" problem, derive a requirement out of it and try to satisfy that requirement. It will be much easier to solve the problem because SO users will have a much larger area for ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is still static state.  You're clearing buffers that could have data that wasn't written to disk.

I imagine this scenario is happening 1.4% of the time.

```
ms1 fills up, empty buffer1 thread started, switch to ms2
empty buffer1 is writing to disk
ms2 fills up, empty buffer2 thread started, switch to ms1
empty buffer1 to disk finishes
ms1 is cleared while it is the active stream
```

When doing multi-threaded programming, static *classes* are fine but static *state* is not.  Ideally you have no shared memory between threads and your code is entirely dependent on it.

Think of it this way -- if you're expecting a value to consistently change, it's not exactly [static](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/static) is it?

Comment: i have an impression that if my variable is not static, it will get a new one every time so i would not be able to fill up my memorystream and output it on the file, am i wrong?

Comment: i change my variable to non-static and i am not able to perform a write at all, i guess that the variable get redeclare every time and never fill up, and hence never write into file. i try change the buffer size and see if performance improve